# mozilla web-audio processing fails on streams

Tags: web-audio-api

My objective is to process talk-radio audio streams with compression and eq, from the `<audio>` element.

In FF 32.0.03 the stream downloads, but no sound.
There's no error shown in firebug.

I tried this code from both `file:///` and `localhost` (wamp).

I commented-out the web-audio `<script>`, the streams played as expected in FF both from `file:///` and from `localhost`.
I removed the comments, returned it to original code.

Next, I ran this in Google Chrome 38.0.2125.101 m (same code, same url src), it ran as expected, worked fine, compressor was effective.

As before, I ran the script from both `file:///` and `localhost` on Chrome, both worked without a hitch.

I suspect one of three things:

- This may be collateral damage from a security (SOP perhaps?) decision.
- It's a Mozilla web-audio bug.
- It may require user interaction (but clicking the play-arrow should satisfy that).

I tried the moz-ask a question help area, but haven't heard anything.
I got on Mozilla dev-webdev list thinking I could get answers, but didn't get much back.

I'm hoping someone on SOF who's more knowledgeable about cross-browser web-audio might shed some light on this, it'd be a pity if FF was restricted from processing streamed audio because of a security decision, I'm hoping this is a bug.

Mozilla's original code example:
http://mdn.github.io/compressor-example/

I changed the `<audio>` src from the example's mp3 files to a stream.
This is the script I ran in the above tests:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>Compressor example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Compressor example</h1>
    <audio controls>  
      <!-- the following line is my only change -->
      <source src="http://74.202.111.236:2512/;" type="audio/mp3">   
    </audio>
    <button data-active="false">Add compression</button>
  </body>

<script>
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

var myAudio = document.querySelector('audio');
var pre = document.querySelector('pre');
var myScript = document.querySelector('script');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

// Create a MediaElementAudioSourceNode
// Feed the HTMLMediaElement into it
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);

// Create a compressor node
var compressor = audioCtx.createDynamicsCompressor();
compressor.threshold.value = -50;
compressor.knee.value = 40;
compressor.ratio.value = 12;
compressor.reduction.value = -20;
compressor.attack.value = 0;
compressor.release.value = 0.25;

// connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the destination
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);

button.onclick = function() {
  var active = button.getAttribute('data-active');
  if(active == 'false') {
    button.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
    button.innerHTML = 'Remove compression';

    source.disconnect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.connect(compressor);
    compressor.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  } else if(active == 'true') {
    button.setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
    button.innerHTML = 'Add compression';

    source.disconnect(compressor);
    compressor.disconnect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting. The audio stops playing the second one executes the  `createMediaElementSource`. Which seems to make sense. But it doesn't start playing again when one connects the new mediaElementSource to the audioContext. :S

Comment: The MediaElementSource seems to be very broken in FireFox at the moment (testing in FF33). I'm getting very inconsistent behaviour where sometimes it works ok, but more often that not the audio is choppy or doesn't work at all.

Comment: I've decoded to file this as a bug, we'll see if this results in any confirmation or not:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1083622

Comment: Make that: I've -decided- ... typo

Comment: UPDATE: the bug I filed has been categorized as one of three duplicates and is resolved in: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=996685. The resolution is that streaming audio is subject to Same Origin Policy in Mozilla. See: 'wip patch' on the above link to see the actual code. Looks like it's Chrome for any devs that want to use web-audio api to process cross-domain streams, unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this simply for closure. It's not the answer I was looking for, but it is the answer that Mozilla has provided.

As I commented above, bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=996685 has listed three other bug reports, including mine, as having fallen victim to Same Origin Policy.

There is an 04/15/2014 patch to the Mozilla code-base that illustrates the changes, available as an attachment to 996685.

Thanks to all who've taken a look.